# how to make horizontal ribbon in table

Tags: html, css, html-table, frontend, ribbon

currently i have table like these

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <table class="table">
          <tr>
            <td><span class="test2">S1</span></td>
            <td class="pic" rowspan="2"><img src="images/image.jpg" alt=""> </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>
              <span class="rub">hahahaha</span><br>
              hahaha<br>
              <span class="rub">ferix tom</span>
            </th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="prof">
          <script>
          <!--
          var birthday = "1980/11/03";
          document.write(birthday converter(birthday));
          //-->
          </script>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="prof">90</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
```

which produce table like this picture [image: before]

how to produce ribbon on the S1 span

i tried using http://www.css3d.net/ribbon-generator/#preview

but it's not covering the table

what my boss wants, look like this [image: after]

please help css master

Answer (score 0):

found the answer, using these

```
          <tr>              
            <td><span class="rub2"><br></span></td>
            <p class="ribbon">this is ribbon</p>
            <td class="pic" rowspan="4"><img src="images/image.jpg" alt=""> </td>
          </tr>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4xwzuqpn/3/